# Keeping the backend code hidden from frontend developers

Tags: python, web-development, source-code, django, frontend

Working on a middle-sized web-based project, we need a way to reasonably manage the source code among backend and frontend developers. I’m wondering if there are some good practices for effective collaboration **without** the need of **sharing** the **backend code** with frontend developers (for various, including security reasons).

Our platform is Django, so the backend is comprised of Python/Django files and the frontend consists of Django Template files (HTML templates), CSS, JavaScript and static files (images, etc…). I’d like to have a comfortable way for frontend developers to do their job without needing an access to the backend code.

My first idea was to create a separate “demo” backend containing all the view functions, but using some static data to pass to the templates. I’m curious though if there is something better, perhaps some specialized tool for this. Ideally, something that the frontend developers would be able to use directly in their browser (perhaps a plugin?) without the need to even run a devel server. After all, all they need to test/see is the template inheritance and rendering.

Any thoughts or experience with this?

Comment: It's called "documentation".

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think you either have not read the whole question or do not understand the topic. No documentation will render your templates as far as I know :-)